# How POST a multiple lookup values to SharePoint via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: json, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to `POST` a new `listItem` to my custom SharePoint list with Microsoft Graph. It worked well until I added one specific custom column: `involvedId`. This is a lookup column that allows multiple values.

Here is the return of actual valid values (shortened for readability):

```
"Title": "Test1",
"refNumber": "Test1",
"clientIdLookupId": "4",
"involvedId": [
{
    "LookupId": 3,
    "LookupValue": "3"
},
{
    "LookupId": 6,
    "LookupValue": "6"
},
{
    "LookupId": 7,
    "LookupValue": "7"
}
]
```

So I tried an insert with the following request body:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "I9",
    "refNumber": "I9",
    "clientIdLookupId": "1",
    "involvedId": [
      {
        "LookupId": 2,
        "LookupValue": "2"
      },
      {
        "LookupId": 3,
        "LookupValue": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get the return code `400 (invalidRequest)`.

I can't find any documentation on how to POST properly multiple values. 
Can anyone help?